# Panel открывается за canvas

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

В иерархии у меня есть 2 canvas'а: 1 - обыкновенный, на нем находится все основное. 2-canvas магазина, таких два. В расположение этих canvas'ов есть объект panel. Так вот, первый canvas магазина открывается поверх основного canvas'а, а второй - за объектами основного canvas'а. Как сделать, чтобы второй открывался так, как и первый canvas - поверх основного canvas'а?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообщем, проблему решил. Это untiy показывает на что он способен в плане багов. Сегодня снова открыл проект и все встало на свои места!

Answer (score 1):

В иерархии второго Canvas переместите panel в самый низ списка дочерних объектов, если сейчас это не так. Должно заработать.

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/DJFG2 сейчас у меня все вот-так. Что куда девать, не понимаю

Comment: Я не правильно понял, думал что оба магазина располагаются в одном канвасе. В этом случае приоритетный был бы тот, что в списке находится ниже. Я так понимаю, для "shop" и "boost" не предусматриваете работу одновременно, только Canvas и один из них активен? Если так, должно работать нормально, по идеее... Ниже написали, что проблема пропала - не возникало снова?